# Run PHP script from URL, every time when the user refreshes the page

Tags: php, mysql

I need to run a PHP script from another site, without the use of CRON, so that will be called whenever anyone comes or refreshes the page.

The script will perform some kind of update my database, it is possible that it takes several tens of seconds, so I needed to run the PHP script so that it also does not limit the site visitor, from where the script will be called.

But I do not want to make the script really starts up every time someone visits or refreshes the page, I would like to limit one minute and so, before calling the script, I would like to put into MySQL database current time someone (who is the one - the one who was first) arrives or refreshes the page, and in the case where someone just to update the page is first compares the current time with the database from the last call script, and if the difference is less than one minute, so the script does not call, but if more than one minute is executed while the database again writes the current time with the last script execution.

I do not need any response from running the script.
Importantly, it shall not affect the page loading user, where it should be called.

Thanks for help

Comment: script on remote site but update your db ? little confused

Comment: The script is on the same server, meaning it is in a different folder with another domain. Like `web1/index.php` call to `web2/script.php`.

Comment: the i would just use exec, to call it in the background `exec("nohup php web2/script.php  >/dev/null 2>&1 &");`

Comment: `exec();` does not affect the original page to load? and can it go away or update during what is in the background will make updates to the database by using the second script?

Comment: well exec does, but the exec part will be over in a fraction of a second. then web2/script.php will be running from the php cli in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a jQuery AJAX call in background after the page is load, so the user wont wait the script finish to load the page

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

However, I do not think the way you want to do it is correct. It's possible, but Im not sure if it's usefull.

**Can you split your script in different tasks??** So you can do them before loading the page, and the users wont notice any difference.

Comment: Yes, doing it with an AJAX call is not the way to do it.  He must find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if javascript is not an option you can do a little bit more research on php forking. It's basically php version of Thread but much more limited. So you can actually fork a child php process to run in the background while the main process still doing the usual thing. So it won't affect your day to day process.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: OK, I'm not against using JS, although I would prefer all done in PHP code, but all I care about is to call the PHP script and let him perform. But will perform about 45 sec. This means that during that time, any user will be able to interrupt the transmission of that site updates, or leave the site, and at this moment I do not want to be interrupted in the background of the implementation of the script, if it's possible? It has to be a substitute for CRON jobs. A PHP script that will update a lot of data in a table, so I wanted to treat even one minute delay in writing MySQL trigger time.